# error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘int’ and ‘class’)

Tags: c++

I having some problems with my code and I don't know what it's wrong.
The error is: error:

no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘int’ and ‘Matrix2D’)
  m = 2 + m; // operator + (3)

And my code is:

```
Matrix2D Matrix2D :: operator + (const int & number){
TipoBase **tmp;

tmp = new int * [rows];

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        tmp[i] = new int [cols];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
            tmp[i][j] = info[i][j] + number;
        }
    }

return(tmp);
```

}

Comment: Unfortunately, in C++ `Matrix2D + int` is something very much different than `int + Matrix2D`

Comment: aside:  do yourself a favour and use std::vector or std::array rather than new/delete.  If you can't do that - then use a std::unique/shared ptr.
and if you STILL can't do that, write your own smart pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've overloaded `operator+` as a *member function* which allows you to do `m + 2`.

If you want to do `2 + m`, you have to provide an overload as a (friend?) *function* as well :

```
Matrix2D operator+(const int& i, const Matrix2D& m){
  return m + i;
}
```